# FetchXML - Today - minus 30 days

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml

I am attempting to create a FetchXML script that retrieves records with a date of today minus 30 days.

Below is the SQL that works.  Could somebody help me with the FetchXML, please?

```
SELECT *
FROM [students]
WHERE start_date = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE()))
```

Thanks in advance,

Richard

Answer (score 3):

FetchXml does not have option for this problem.

It can be achieved using combination of Last X Days and OlderThan X Days.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="students">
    <attribute name="name" />
      <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="start_date" value="30" operator="last-x-days"/>
        <condition attribute="start_date" value="29" operator="olderthan-x-days"/>
      </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 0):

FetchXml provides only limited support this specific problem.

You will have to calculate the target date yourself and pass it as a filter value:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="account">
    <attribute name="name" />
      <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="createdon" operator="on" value="2015-03-13" />
      </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

If you didn't already try: Use Advanced Find to explore the built-in filters supported for DateTime attributes via downloading the generated FetchXml.